# Spring Batch Can we have in memory for batch job and application have other data source

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

Spring batch can we have in memory for batch job and for application level we have other data source like db postgres. Could you please help me on this?
extends class DefaultBatchConfigurer and override the public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
But it reset the datasource for the application level.